# parent: Error: Cannot drop table 'dealers' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'cars_ibfk_1' on table 'cars'

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, node-mysql2

I just cloned my project from my github account. I spin the server and i'm getting
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
parent: Error: Cannot drop table 'dealers' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'cars_ibfk_1' on table 'cars'.
sql: 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Dealers`;',
parameters: undefined

I expected to get a table created in my local mysql database with no errors. I tried checking the connection host if it matches one with my installed mysql connection.

Comment: Would you mind posting your model initialization/configuration where your application is creating your tables? Based upon your description, it sounds like you're using `Model.sync`, which can sometimes attempt to forcefully delete tables before recreating them. Please ensure the order/flow of the code is clear to the reader too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error. It had to do with the order I created the tables. so I had two tables 'user' and 'cars'. The cars table belonged to the user table. Since I already worked on the code from another computer, I've created the user table before the cars table but I called the `car.sync()` before the user. Running npm start after importing the project in another project caused the error. You can't create a child table 'cars' before the parent table 'user'.

Initially, it was:

```
await Car.sync();
await User.sync();
```

So I corrected it to:

```
await User.sync();
await Car.sync();
```